# Refile gives Sinatra::NotFound: Sinatra::NotFound in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, refile

I added refile for file uploading in my rails 4.2 app. But now I starting to see Sinatra::NotFound when a user mistypes an url.
What can I do to prevent it so it displays the correct error page?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a 'catch all' route. Basically, if the url is mistyped your application will reroute to a default route:

```
get '/*' do
  redirect "http://whateverYouWant.com"
end
```